# Jira spring application plugin not accessing angular assets folder

Tags: java, angular, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am new to Jira and I have created one application and her I have used atlassian-scanner and also I have included angular project everything is working but when any rest request is getting called from main.js it is not working, not sure what is happening is it not considering assets folder or what please help.

Here is my below code for xml web-resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bundles>
<web-resource key="client-resources" name="Client Resources">

    <resource name="assets/" type="download" location="client/assets/" />
    <resource name="main.js" type="download" location="client/main.js" />
<context>com.ngdemo.client-resources</context>
</web-resource>
</bundles>
```

and my index.html code as below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/jira/plugins/servlet/demo/" />
    <meta name="decorator" content="atl.general" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    $webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("com.ngdemo.client-resources")
</head>
<body>

<app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

the url which is wrong it is as below:

```
http://localhost:2990/jira/plugins/servlet/demo/assets/i18n/en.json
```

but instead I think it should be as below like main.js:

```
 http://localhost:2990/jira/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-CDN/-ufur03/713000/b6b48b2829824b869586ac216d119363/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.demo.ngdemo:client-resources/main.js

 http://localhost:2990/jira/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-CDN/-ufur03/713000/b6b48b2829824b869586ac216d119363/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.demo.ngdemo:client-resources/assets/i18n/en.json
```